# Xbee module and bluetooth module

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, xbee

Is it possible to connect Xbee module (Using Xbee shield) as well as Bluetooth module at the same time to any of the Arduino boards like Uno? Most of the sites give information about connecting one module at a time to Arduino boards.

Comment: You probably should mention which Bluetooth module you want to communicate with.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  You might like to know there is an [Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the Uno only has one UART. You have to communicate with the Bluetooth module via the Software Serial Library on some appropriate GPIO. The XBee shield could of course also use the Software Serial Library if it is removed from the Uno and attached with wires to the appropriate Uno GPIOs.

Comment: Well thanks for the reply.Am new to arduino & doesnt hav any hands on experience with arduino projects.The reason why i have mentioned Uno is that they are readily available in my college.

And my project consist of creating an RC controlled remote car with the help of an android app & hence require a bluetooth module for communication.
[ref: http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-RC-car-for-beginners-Android-control-over-/?ALLSTEPS]and Doesnt know to choose the right bluetooth module.

And secondly I need more than 2 Rc cars which can communicate with each other through xbee series 1 modules.

Comment: The BT modules in the link would work. You might want to try this out with the BT module on the UART first, then add the XBee shield car-to-car communication later when everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some board like the [BLEduino](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/kytelabs/bleduino-bluetooth-40-ble-made-easy-arduino-compat) connected to a [zigbee-breakout board](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=3787) can do the trick for you.

Comment: It might be worth adding some more details on that board and how it would help solve the problem to save anyone having to go out and search for the info themselves. It's more like a comment at the moment.